# Web font support in MudBlazor

Tags: mudblazor

I have some adobe web fonts provided by a stylesheet link and I want to add these fonts to a MudTheme so I can use them in my web app.

```
<--link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/gbt1fwk.css"-->
```

Any ideas how to do that? The Typography section of the manual is quite minimal and does not explain how to use external fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Style` and set `font-family`. For example:

```
<MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true" Style="font-family: aktiv-grotesk-extended">Hello, world!</MudText>
```

Comment: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/maQQEfGFiQPMUmRM